# Cannot read property 'range' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
  var approval = e.range.getvalue();
  
  if(approval == "Approved")
  {
  
    e.source.getActiveSheet()
  //.getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStamp)
  //.setValue(new Date());
    
    MailApp.sendEmail("ishwarisaskar@gmail.com", "Approved", "In If loop");
  
  }else
  {
  
    MailApp.sendEmail("ishwarisaskar@gmail.com", "Approved", "In Else loop");
    return;
    
  }
  
}
```

Facing error I want Sheet edited time in Column
what should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `getvalue()` should be `getValue()`, therefore:

```
var approval = e.range.getValue();
```

you are actually checking for every cell that was edited whether it contains 'Approved' or not.

Alternatively, if you want, you can be more specific on how to request a value from a particular sheet. Here is an example how you could request cell *A1* from the sheet with the name *Sheetname* or the active sheet.

You could request **approval** like that :

```
var approval =e.source.getSheetByName('Sheetname').getRange('A1').getValue();
```

or

```
var approval = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue();
```

In the second case, you are only checking for cell *A1*, while in the first case you are checking for every cell that is edited whether it contains 'Approved' or not.